# Angular 1 dependancy injection with JavaScript and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out how to use TypeScript in an existing Angular 1.5 app. I can't figure out how to inject custom services. Angular services and 3rd party services work fine. The services I need to inject are still vanilla JS services. In the example below I need to inject reportService.

The error I get is getReportById is not a function.

```
class ReportController implements IReportController {

    static $inject = ['$stateParams', 'reportService'];


    constructor(private $stateParams: angular.ui.IStateParamsService, private reportService) {

        this.getReport($stateParams.id);
    }

    getReport(id: number): object {
        reportService.getReportById(id)
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            });
    }

}
```

Here is the service.

```
angular.module('reportsServiceModule', [])
    .factory('reportsService', [
        '$http',
        reportsService
    ]);

function reportsService(
        $http
) {

    'use strict';

    var service = {};

    service.getReportById = function(reportID) {
        return 'A promise';
    };

    return service;
}
```

Comment: And what is reportService?

Comment: reportService is a regular angular 1 service (could be any service) written in JavaScript (no TypeScript).

Comment: Please, provide the code for it. It matters. For any service you can use `any` type, but you won't benefit from TS this way. Do you have particular problems with the code above?

Comment: Adding any doesn't fix the issue, I've added the service structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real difference between JS and TS development in AngularJS is that the units can be typed. This doesn't affect anything but type safety.

Here it would be

```
interface IReportService {
 getReportById: (someType) => string;
}

...
constructor(
  private $stateParams: angular.ui.IStateParamsService,
  private reportService: IReportService
) {
...
```

There's no problem with dependency injection. If you have DI problem in Angular, you get an error from injector.

The real problem here is that strict mode isn't used. With `use strict` statement or [`alwaysStrict` TS option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) the error would show what's really wrong - `reportService` variable is not defined in `getReport` method.

Instead, it should be

```
getReport(id: number): object {
    this.reportService.getReportById(id)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out later in the day and this was the issue. I also had an order issue with my constructor, I had added another variable not shown above and didn't realize it could also break the injection.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo.

You defined a report**s**Service

> .factory('reportsService')

But injected a different one

> static $inject = ['$stateParams', 'reportService'];

Comment: It's true that there is a typo. However, it was made in the question, not in the original code. Otherwise there would be DI error, not ' getReportById is not a function'.